# Configfs like file system for userspace

Tags: filesystems, fuse

Currently, I have an application that does file creation/read/write on a configfs file system. My configfs handlers call functions defined in another kernel module which talks to a device. Each configfs file corresponds to an object in the kernel and read/write on that file/object are mapped to device actions.

Recently, we have moved to userspace devices. We now have a userspace library that can directly talk to the devices. 
So, I want to migrate this application to use userspace lib APIs. The application will create the same files it did previously but on a userspace filesystem, for e.g. The handlers for these operations will now be the userspace library APIs. Basically, userspace library will replace the driver

So far, I have looked into FUSE. The problem that I see is that it allows handlers only for generic operations like read/write/mkdir etc. I would like to more fine grained control like configfs provides. For e.g., I want to be able to say what happens when I create a ***named*** directory, what happens when I read/write to a ***named*** file etc.

Any help on such a file sytem, or any other approach is appreaciated.

Edit:
As @muru mentioned in the comments, I would rather avoid looking at file names in the userspace handler themselves. This is because part of what the current configfs handlers do is create other files. 
So if I do that, I have this loopy kind of a situation where my userspace handlers create files and that creation itself has other handlers. Maybe possible but seems ugly to me.

Comment: What's stopping your handlers from looking at the ***name***s of the things they're being asked to read/write, and handling them appropriately?

Comment: You are right, I should have been clearer about this. Part of what the existing configfs handlers do is create other files. So now, I have this loopy kind of a situation where handlers create files and that creation itself has other handlers. Maybe possible but seems ugly to me.

Comment: @muru I have edited the question details